# Source in Meta.extra_kwargs do not add to fields

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have few django models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(
        _('phone number'), max_length=16,
        unique=True, blank=True, null=True,
        default=None, validators=[phone_validator]
    )
    ...

class UserExtension(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Worker(UserExtension):
    # some fields

class Administrator(UserExtension):
    # some fields
```

View:

```
class AdministratorListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    queryset = Administrator.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.AdministratorSerializer
```

And serializer:

```
class AdministratorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Administrator
        fields = ('network', 'email')
        extra_kwargs = {'email': {'source': 'user.email'}}
```

But this is not working. Following traceback tell about field does not exist for my model:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 201, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 48, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 765, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 262, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 683, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 683, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 510, in to_representation
    fields = self._readable_fields
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 376, in _readable_fields
    field for field in self.fields.values()
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 363, in fields
    for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1047, in get_fields
    source, info, model, depth
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1192, in build_field
    return self.build_unknown_field(field_name, model_class)
  File "/home/vagrant/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1304, in build_unknown_field
    (field_name, model_class.__name__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `user.email` is not valid for model `Administrator`.
```

I looked at the source code and realized that the value from 'source' is passed to build_field as field_name argument and rest-framework simply cannot find this field ('user.email') in my model (Administrator)

[part of get_fields method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SLNV.png)

[build_field method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsHa7.png)